# SVN working copy upgrade borked, any hope of recovering?

Tags: svn

In the middle of upgrading my working copy from 1.6 to 1.7 I had a power failure. When I try to go back to finish the upgrade I get an error: svn:E200030: Table "REPOSITORY" exists already. Is there any hope of recovering this working copy or is it FUBAR?

If I can recover it, what steps should I follow?

Comment: what commands are you trying to use to upgrade?

Comment: I use the client smartSVN, I'm not exactly sure which commands it uses. I got a new PC, so I installed the latest version of the client, as soon as it starts it informs me I need to upgrade the WC for this version. My options are to upgrade or quit. I click upgrade.

Comment: Was the power failure on the working copy, the repository, or both?  (i.e. client, server, or both)

Comment: Client only... I kicked the power strip :( and must now take the walk of shame. I may have jumped the gun posting this question though. It's looking like the slikSVN client is able to do the upgrade, so it may have been a problem specifically with smartSVN. Will update when/if slik finishes.

Comment: Its probably an issue with temporary files that were created but not deleted, and its tripping over them still being there.

Comment: Totally agree. While upgrade .svn/tmp/wcng directory is created where WC 1.7 database is generated. When generation is finished, new database is moved to wc.db. So your original working copy data is untouched. You should simply remove everything in ".svn/tmp" directory and retry upgrade. When upgrade is finished, SmartSVN will check your working copy correctness automatically.

Comment: Never got to try out Dmitry's fix. SlikSVN was able to do the upgrade and SmartSVN is able to work with the WC now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SlikSVN was able to pick up and fix where SmartSVN was failing. Not sure what or why.